# $ n $ different variances, same mean, what is the maximum-likelihood estimator of $ \mu $?

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Observations $ X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are drawn from normal populations with the same mean $ \mu $ but with different variances $ \sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2,\ldots, \sigma_n^2 $. Is it possible to estimate all the parameters? If we assume that the $ \sigma_i^2 $ are known, what is the maximum-likelihood estimator of $ \mu $?

My attempt:

The likelihood function is
$$ L(x_1,\ldots,x_n; \mu, \sigma_1,\ldots, \sigma_n) = \frac 1 {(2\pi)^{n/2}} \prod_{i=1}^n \dfrac 1 {\sigma_i} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2\sigma_i^2} }$$

Then we take the natural logarithm. We derive with respect to $ \sigma_i$  and we equate these derivatives to zero. We obtain

$$ -\frac 1 {\sigma_i} + \frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma_i^3} = 0 $$

From here we get that

$$ \widehat{\sigma_i} = X_i - \mu$$

Is this correct?

Analogously for the other question but now we derive with respect to $ \mu $.

Comment: From $-\dfrac 1 {\sigma_i} + \dfrac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{\sigma_i^3} = 0$ you get $ 
\sigma_i = |X_i-\mu|. \qquad $

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are right. Is the rest of the solution correct?

Comment: It's correct if you take $\mu$ to be known. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy If $ \mu $ is not known, then an estimator would be $ \vert X_{i} - \overline{X} \vert $, It is right?

Comment: When $\mu$ is not known and $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n$ are, then a weighted average with weights proportional to $\sigma_i^{-2}$ is often used, although I haven't worked out whether that would be the MLE in this situation.